# How to redirect correctly using header in php?

Tags: php

My code -

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<?php
    session_start();    

    if(isset($_POST["subLogin"]))
    {
        $uname = trim($_POST["tbUser"]);
        $pass = $_POST["pasUser"];
        if($uname == "") 
        {
            header('Location: index.php?e=1');
        }
        else if($pass == "") 
        {
            header('Location: index.php?e=2');
        }
        $unameF = "";
        $passF = "";    

        $userfile = fopen("DB/userDB.txt", "r");
        while(!feof($userfile))
        {    

            $arr1 = explode(":", fgets($userfile));
            $unameF = trim($arr1[1]);
            $arr1 = explode(":", fgets($userfile));
            $passF = trim($arr1[1]);
            $arr1 = explode(":", fgets($userfile));
            $type = trim($arr1[1]);
            if($unameF == $uname)
            {
                $_SESSION["uname"] = $uname;
                $_SESSION["type"] = $type;
                header('Location: welcome.php');
            }
        }
        header("Location: index.php?e=0");
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Here, "header("Location: index.php?e=0");" always gets executed even if the username matches. And "welcome.php" is never reached. If "header("Location: index.php?e=0");" this line is commented out, then it works fine. Any solutions??

Comment: Have you tried exit() ?

Comment: Add `exit;` after all `header()` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call exit() after your redirect.

```
header('Location: index.php?e=1');
exit();
```